# CodeIgniter - Autoload for views?

Tags: codeigniter

is there any way to load a view (for header or footer) on every function (in a controller)? I have a couple of `if/else` statements there and it would be a pain to change it all when I'll need to.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can load the view in the `__construct` function at the top of your controller. Take
a look at the PHP manual on [Constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

```
function __construct()
{      
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load>-view('your_view');

}
```

If the `header` and `footer` are going to be constant and required components for the visual part of your site, but you may want to load a different content portion between your header and footer, then you can make a function that will take an argument.

```
 private function doViews($argument) 
 {


        $this->load->view('header');

        $this->load->view($argument);

        $this->load->view('footer');


       return NULL;
 }
```

You may want to have an array of available views inside the `doViews` function in order to do proper validation that the file exists. Then you simply call the function in each method in your controller like this:

```
$this->doViews('main_content');
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I, for some reason, didn't realize that I can do in `__construct` more that just load a model ;) But how about a footer?

Comment: Its just a function, you can do a lot with it.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't realize it. Can you tell me about that footer?

Comment: What footer? If you have content before the footer, then you'll have to load the content before the footer. Unless you make a function to load your views and have an argument, for which content you'll want loaded

Comment: No no. I have it like this
- header
- content
- footer

So what I am asking is - can I automatically load footer (like loading header in `__construct()`)?

Comment: This seems to be the most sensible approach, especially for apps which may have slight differences in the header - for example whether or not the user is signed in, or loading different JS libraries depending on what functionality is needed on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a Template library like this: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template

Then all you need to is put this in the controller (can be in __construct or within a method)

```
$this->template->set_partial('header', 'layouts/header');
$this->template->set_partial('footer', 'layouts/footer');
$this->template->set_partial('sidebar', 'layouts/sidebar');
```

Then to send data like you do with a view:

```
$this->template->build('create', $this->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create your main_view ... as a master page that already has a structure:

main_view.php

```
$this->load>-view('header');
<?php //get content here
?>
$this->load>-view('footer');
```

If you want to change something in the header or footer (through a statement) you can add content:

```
function __construct()
{      
        parent::__construct();

        $data['footer'] = ($a == 'foo') ? 'footer one' : 'footer two';

        $data_to_main = $this->load->view('template/footer', $data, TRUE);

        $data_to_main = 'others';

        $this->load>-view('main_view', $data_to_main);
}
```